# how to get the rows from A file by excluding any MbrIds in B file? A is pipe delimited file

Tags: unix, ksh

File A is pipe delimited, 5 million rows:

```
600000002233199881|1000109668|2019-05-10|
600000002233199700|1000002681|2019-05-10|
600000002233199701|1000003390|2019-05-10|
```

File B has only 1 column ids, 1 k rows:

```
1000002681
1000109668
```

How can I get the rows from A file excluding the Ids in B file? The expected output is:

```
600000002233199701|1000003390|2019-05-10|
```

I tried `grep -Fwf fileB fileA`  from this link below, but doesn't work for my case. I wonder how to change it to work.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110645/select-lines-from-text-file-which-have-ids-listed-in-another-file

Comment: Do you want to `grep` in the whole line, or only matches in column 2? Do you want to find `600000001000109668|1000000000|2019-05-10|` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude, you need the `-v` flag.

Try `grep -Fvwf fileB fileA`. Make sure there is no empty line at the end of fileB.

```
$ cat fileA 
600000002233199881|1000109668|2019-05-10|
600000002233199700|1000002681|2019-05-10|
600000002233199701|1000003390|2019-05-10|
$ cat fileB
1000002681
1000109668
$ grep -Fvwf fileB fileA
600000002233199701|1000003390|2019-05-10|
$
```